# NullPointerException during orientation change

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, orientation, fragment

I want to build app that has different layouts for different orietation mode. So I built my project likewise did it android tutorial [[example here]](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html). But with one difference, this tutorial was creating for different size(normal and large) when I want for variety orientation mode(landscape, portrait, etc). And now I am getting a `NullPointerException` during the orientation change.
Here is my code:

HeadlinesFragment:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {

   OnHeadlineSelectedListener HeadlinesCallback;
   List<Person> personLista = new ArrayList<Person>();

   public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(Person person);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

        //TESTOWE WYPENIENIE
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            personLista.add(new Person("Imie"+i+"Nazwisko"+i,"email"+i+"@example"+i+".com"));
        }
        String[] niceTime = new String[personLista.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<personLista.size(); i++){
            niceTime[i] = personLista.get(i).getName();
        }
        //KONIEC

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, niceTime));
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
        // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.person_view) != null) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try{
            HeadlinesCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener)activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " have to implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        HeadlinesCallback.onArticleSelected(personLista.get(position));

        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
```

}

PersonFragment:

```
public class PersonFragment extends Fragment{
   public static Person person;
   ImageView icon;
   TextView text1;
   TextView text2;
   TextView text3;

    View view;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       if(savedInstanceState != null){
           person = (Person)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("person");
       }

       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_view, container, false);

       icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
       text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
       text2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.email);
       text3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.info);

       return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            person = (Person)args.getSerializable("context");

            text1.setText(person.getName());
            text2.setText(person.getEmail());
            text3.setText("Quisque semper ultricies iaculis. Vestibulum nec metus adipiscing, egestas sem mattis, ornare nulla. Quisque nec nibh nec lacus euismod gravida. Proin at pretium enim. In auctor, nisi sit amet pharetra facilisis, est justo mattis mi, eget mattis tortor ligula non orci. Vestibulum neque augue, elementum vitae aliquam non, condimentum ac dui. Nullam ultricies velit nec diam aliquam, sed lacinia sem eleifend. Quisque quam sapien, sodales id suscipit nec, consequat vel nunc. Quisque eu velit nisi. Donec varius consequat metus, tempor semper tortor ultricies vel. Mauris eget arcu nisi. Proin sit amet dui nisl. Quisque auctor lobortis augue sit amet egestas. Fusce mattis aliquam ante, et bibendum nibh ullamcorper et. Integer ipsum nibh, placerat a felis ut, accumsan rutrum eros. Quisque lacinia facilisis ipsum sed commodo.");
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        }else{
            if(person==null){
                person = new Person("Test Testowy", "Testowy@gmail.com");
            }
            updateArticleView(person);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("person", person);
    }
    public void updateArticleView(Person externalPerson) {
        this.person = externalPerson;

        text1.setText(externalPerson.getName());
        text2.setText(externalPerson.getEmail());
        text3.setText("Quisque semper ultricies iaculis. Vestibulum nec metus adipiscing, egestas sem mattis, ornare nulla. Quisque nec nibh nec lacus euismod gravida. Proin at pretium enim. In auctor, nisi sit amet pharetra facilisis, est justo mattis mi, eget mattis tortor ligula non orci. Vestibulum neque augue, elementum vitae aliquam non, condimentum ac dui. Nullam ultricies velit nec diam aliquam, sed lacinia sem eleifend. Quisque quam sapien, sodales id suscipit nec, consequat vel nunc. Quisque eu velit nisi. Donec varius consequat metus, tempor semper tortor ultricies vel. Mauris eget arcu nisi. Proin sit amet dui nisl. Quisque auctor lobortis augue sit amet egestas. Fusce mattis aliquam ante, et bibendum nibh ullamcorper et. Integer ipsum nibh, placerat a felis ut, accumsan rutrum eros. Quisque lacinia facilisis ipsum sed commodo.");
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }
```

}

and MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!=null){

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, new HeadlinesFragment()).commit();

    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onArticleSelected(Person person) {

    PersonFragment fragment = (PersonFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.person_view);

    if(fragment!=null){
        fragment.updateArticleView(person);
    }else{
        PersonFragment newFragment = new PersonFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("context", person);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

}

PROBLEM:
in beginning everything is ok, but when i change orientation mode to landscape(in emulator ctrl+f12) and again I back to portain and I select some stuff from listview I get "unfortunately application has stopped".

It is logcat:

```
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.example.friendslist.PersonFragment.updateArticleView(PersonFragment.java:68)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.example.friendslist.MainActivity.onArticleSelected(MainActivity.java:43)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.example.friendslist.HeadlinesFragment.onListItemClick(HeadlinesFragment.java:69)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-02 14:29:03.396: E/AndroidRuntime(802):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My main problem is that I always looking for something like "caused by", here i didn't had it. Can someone tell me where is a problem ?

P.S in normal android example, when i change name of sub folder from layout-large to layout-land I have the same problem.

Activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

person_view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Imie i nazwisko" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="email@sample.com" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="info" />
```

main activity in land subfolder:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.example.friendslist.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.example.friendslist.PersonFragment"
          android:id="@+id/person_view"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: what is line 66 in the fragment?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 14:06:14.696: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at com.example.friendslist.PersonFragment.updateArticleView(PersonFragment.java:66)`  It's the first line - line 66 as Raghunandan says

Comment: "icon = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.icon);" i think that it just first induction findViewById method.P.S this line is from updateArticleView method(last method in PersonFragment). How i can get icon referent in other way ?

Comment: @bkowalczyyk move all your initialization to `onCreateView` like  `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_view, container, false);
        icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);`

Comment: again the same problem, but with one difference, now i have null pointer in text1.setText(externalPerson.getName()); .. how it is possible that i have empty textView...

Comment: @bkowalczyyk did you initialize all your views in `onCreateView` ? and is `externalPerson` initialized?

Comment: I add my xml -I am initializing everything, I studied activity and fragment life cycle and it should works, but doesn't work...

Comment: @bkowalczyyk post your updated code.

Comment: done, but i think that getView should works too.

Comment: which line gives you NPE now?  check if this line is null `person = (Person)args.getSerializable("context");`

Comment: look at logcat, lang.NullPointerException at PersonFragment(line 68) this is text1.setText(externalPerson.getName());

Comment: @bkowalczyyk `text1` is initialized so its `externalPerson` is null

Comment: no, text, and text 2 is null, because i add if(text1!=null) to updateArticleView method and it works that nothing happen so text1==null is true.

Comment: On another note: "caused by" would appear when the thrown exception (the exception caught) is wrapped around another exception (the actual cause).

Answer (score 1):

OK, after fight with this problem, I found solution, I changed condition in `onArticleSelected` method from `(fragment!=null)` to `findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)`. I don't know why, after orientation change fragment was still being, maybe someone can explain me it.

EDIT:// if someone will want to cheeck orientation setings, agains cheeck that some element is equal null, you can do it simpler, for example: `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`